# How to get same height for all divs with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So im using flex and i have divs in two rows, but problem is that he calculate seperate first and second row.I have same height for divs in first row and then same height in divs in second row,i want that they all have same height,but without fixed heigh This is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/38fvkxt1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="div">
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>
</div>

<div class="div">
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>
</div>
<div class="div">
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>

</div>
<div class="div">
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>
</div>

<div class="div">
  1 <br/>
</div>
<div class="div">
  1 <br/>
  1 <br/>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you can only get the same height for all elements on the same row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer  [https://jsfiddle.net/8cokL3c2/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/8cokL3c2/1/)
use jquery jquery-2.2.4.min.js and add this

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$("div").each(function() {
  if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
    maxHeight = $(this).height();
  }
});

$("div").height(maxHeight);
```